# Problems overriding methods

Tags: android, overriding

I have a subclass of RelativeLayout and I am trying to override some methods (all the addView(...) methods) and I am having a strange problem. When generating the overrides from the Source menu I have the below

```
@Override
public void addView(View child)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.addView(child);
}

@Override
public void addView(View child, int index)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.addView(child, index);
}

@Override
public void addView(View child, int width, int height)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.addView(child, width, height);
}

@Override
public void addView(View child, LayoutParams params)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.addView(child, params);
}

@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.addView(child, index, params);
}
```

But the last two throw compile errors of the type

> The method addView(View, int, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) of type RelativeLayoutWithDataState must override or implement a supertype method

looking at the docs these are all API level 1

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View, int, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)

Can anyone shed some light on this, am I being really stupid?!

Thanks!

Comment: Is your project being built with Java 1.5 or 1.6? In eclipse, right-click your project, click Properties, and then go to the Java Compiler section. What is the "Compiler compliance level" property set to?

Comment: thanks but that woudve caused all the methods to throw errors due to the annotations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've imported the wrong LayoutParams. It should be `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and not `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`

That should fix your problem.

Comment: +1 Excellent! Thanks, wouldve taken me ages to spot that! I was too trusting of the source generation...